# Do Graph API Queries Using Field Expansion Support "Since" & "Until"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, field

I am querying the Graph API for information about photos. I'm using field expansion. The queries look like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[userId]?fields=albums.limit(5000).fields(photos.limit(1000).fields(from,comments,likes,tags,place,name,created_time))&access_token=[accessToken]
```

These queries work great.

Is there a way to do this query for a time range i.e. "since (date)" & "until (date)"? I'm trying to only query for photos with a created_time within a certain range.

I tried [this solution](https://graph.facebook.com/%5buserId%5d?fields=albums.limit%285000%29.fields%28photos.limit%281000%29.fields%28from,comments,likes,tags,place,name,created_time%29%29%2a%2a&since=1351731661&until=1358643661&date_format=U%2a%2a&access_token=%5baccessToken%5d) but it didn't work.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.since(unixtime).until(unixtime)`

`me?fields=albums.limit(5000).fields(photos.limit(1000).fields(from,comments,likes,tags,place,name,created_time).since(unixtime).until(unixtime))`